# Timestamp of gtk_window_present_with_time

Tags: gtk

I was wondering what timestamp was needed for the function `gtk_window_present_with_time`. Is it the timestmap returned by `gdk_x11_get_server_time`?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DanD. how did you know that? It wasn't stated in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: X11 uses the timestamps to resolve races between messages from clients such as those involved in focus stealing prevention. And that I already answered a question like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448224/why-python-wnck-window-activateinttime-time

Comment: You can also pass `GDK_CURRENT_TIME` (which is 0) to represent the current time.

Comment: If you present window as a result of some user command, you should probably use `time` of mouse or keyboard event.